# C# set database to specific data that I want

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently trying delete my advertisement. But instead of deleting it from database I just want to set the status from `1` ( which means active ) to `0` (which means inactive). I have tried to use query `UPDATE`. But I do not know the format. My current code is

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteImage", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AdvID", Convert.ToInt32(hfContactID.Value));
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        Clear();
        FillGridView();
        LitMsg.Text = "Deleted Successfully";
        ButSave.Enabled = true;
        Image1.Visible = false;
    }
```

and I believe that `Delete` query does not change my status to `0` so my update query is something like this.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileImgsave.HasFile == true)
        {


            string imgfile = Path.GetFileName(FileImgsave.PostedFile.FileName);
            //FileImgsave.SaveAs("Images/" + imgfile);
            FileImgsave.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + imgfile));
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Advertisement SET Item=@item,ImgPath=@image,Name=@name Where AdvID='" + AdsTb.Text + "'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", imgfile);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", "~/Images/" + imgfile);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
            FillGridView();
            LitMsg.Text = "Update successfully!";
            Clear();
        }
```

Below is my delete query

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteImage]
@AdvID int

AS
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Advertisement
    WHERE AdvID = @AdvID
    END
```

Comment: Please share the code for "DeleteImage" stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to Update the Status

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Advertisement SET Status=0, Item=@item,ImgPath=@image,Name=@name Where AdvID='" + AdsTb.Text + "'";
```

**Status=0**

Comment: set Status=0 does not change the data in database to 0

Comment: Is this "status" a column in your Advertisement Table ?

Comment: yes, but i tried the Status=0 in Item, so i did Item=0, because i'm just testing if it works.

Comment: You need to make sure following things:


First -  On the GridLoad event you need to mention to display only those images whose Status = 1.


Second- Set the status column value to zero when you click update - either at the stored procedure level or in the update query.

Comment: how do i make sure gridview only display those status = 1?

Comment: @JiaHao   If the Status is not updated to 0 in the database,  ---> 1. check if the passed 'AdsTb.Text' contains the correct AdvID.  --->   2. Use the most simple version of the query    "UPDATE Advertisement SET Status=0 Where AdvID='" + AdsTb.Text + "'"  --->    3. Check your connectionstring

Comment: thank you everyone, i manage to finish this part of my project! thanks for your help @everyone